# Getting the condition of a while loop to print out once false

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am doing an exercise on an online course to learn Javascript. This is only the first one and I am having issues, so I really want to understand it before I progress.

The question is this:

`complete the while loop in the editor so it will print out "I'm learning while loops!". Do this by adding the condition between the parentheses—don't change line 5, or you could get an infinite loop!`

The code is:

```
var understand = true;

while(){
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");
    understand = false;
}
```

I tried adding this to the condition:

`while(understand === 0){`

But I am getting this error

Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't print the string to the console. Check your loop syntax!

What am I doing wrong in my condition? Could someone please elaborate, so I can learn the key fundamentals to this. Thanks!

The example before this exercise:

```
var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

while(coinFace === 0){
    console.log("Heads! Flipping again...");
    var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
}
console.log("Tails! Done flipping.");
```

Edit---update:

```
You may have noticed that when we give a variable the boolean value true, we check that variable directly—we don't bother with ===. For instance,

var bool = true;
while(bool){
    //Do something
}
is the same thing as

var bool = true;
while(bool === true){
    //Do something
}
but the first one is faster to type. Get in the habit of typing exactly as much as you need to, and no more!

If you happen to be using numbers, as we did earlier, you could even do:
```

Comment: `while(understand) {`. But yea, you need to read the section about while loops one more time, as you don't really *understand it* yet.

Comment: May I suggest that if this is the _first_ exercise in an online course and you're having problems completing it, perhaps the course isn't of the highest quality as you shouldn't need to be guessing at answers...

Comment: It is a codeacademy course. They showed an example of a while statement and then gave this question afterwords. It looked nothing like the example they gave.

Comment: The course should have taught you about while loop syntax, if it is asking you to write one. Perhaps you should go back and reread/listen to the lesson.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the exercise is correct. His understanding of it isn't, which is why he's asking the question here. It's a valid question, and dfsq answered it.

Comment: @mariocatch But courses should give you the understanding you need to complete the given exercises.  If they don't, then they aren't doing their job.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It explained it briefly in the explanation part before this exercise. It states that the computer sees 0=true and 1=false. So, I thought I had to make `understand === 0` to make it true. I didn't think the computer would just read the word true and understand what it meant. Look at my updated question and it will show the example it showed before this question. This is why I got mixed up.

Comment: @Becky Check that documentation again. 0 is false to computers. 1 is true. Make sure it says that before moving on.

Comment: oops. Sorry, typed it in wrong... `When you use a number in a condition, as we did earlier, JavaScript understands 1 to mean true and 0 to mean false.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `while(understand === true)`

Because the loop will fire the first time, as `understand` is already set to true. Then, as it's firing, it will set `understand` to false- so the next time it tries to fire the loop the condition will fail and it won't continue. This way, you're getting one execution of the loop- thus printing only one time.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I did `while(understand)` because I already had `understand` set to true. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Becky It's important to note that strict comparisons will always be faster to execute and will be less prone to errors. If you do while(understand), understand could be set to a string or array and the while will continue to fire. If you do === true, then you're saying only continue if it's exactly equal to true- so if it got changed at all the while would stop. Just good coding practice, as you're getting into things- try and make your conditions always have either three equal signs or one of the greater/less than comparisons.

Comment: So is there no point in creating the variable then in a global scope and just keep it local inside of that while? Sorry if the terminology is off. Still new.

Comment: I'm afraid that confuses me. You should still initialize the variable before doing any comparison with it.

Comment: In the next exercise it goes over this. It is stating the oposite of what you are saying. Though, it is saying both are correct. I edited my question to show what it says..

Comment: This seconds the fact that this course is not a very good one. Less code is good if you're repeating yourself, but not good if you're leaving your code open to improper functionality, and even less good when someone tries to figure out what you are truly doing with a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you had code that looks like this

```
while(true){
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");
    understand = false;
}
```

you would get an infinite loop! The loop would just keep going because the conditional will always be true. Now if only there were some way, like a variable in the conditional, to make the conditional false.